# How to implement an editable div like the one on WhatsApp Web?

Tags: javascript

Because of Windows not supporting flag emoji I need to implement an editable div which behave like a textarea, so it will be possible to display tag images instead of emoji characters. Does anyone know how to do it and fix strage behaviours like copy/paste to allow only text?

**Edit**

I already know about the attribuite `contenteditable`, but the problem is that it does not behave like a textarea, specially when copy/paste content to/from it. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

maybe contenteditable attribute will wok for you check out [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) guide

Answer (score 0):

Yes,It's possible! If you want to include more future on the editable div then you can use document.execCommand(). For more information about execCommand just visit to:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

Example here:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  This text can be edited by the user.
</div>
```